# Page menu not showing in admin, new Page button missing in toolbar too

Tags: pages, buttons

I need to put a new page on a website using WordPress. However, on the Dashboard there is no Page button on the left hand side or at the top in the *+New* dropdown.

Can anyone please advise me what to do?

Comment: Disable plugins and switch to core-bundled theme, determine what is removing the page post type.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be due to some crash database issue so take dump of database and try to reinstall with fresh copy.

But before perform this long process please try below step for capabilities. The `wp_capabilities` saves the value as serialized array, you can try it in your php or for this example [here](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/).

Using Phpmyadmin (or another MySQL management tool), first backup your database. Then navigate to your `wp_usermeta` table and locate the meta_key called "*wp_capabilities*" for your user_id. Change the meta-value for this record to:

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

Let me know if there is any query/doubt from this.